# How to invert, inverse, hover the icons in zurb foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

How does one invert, reverse, negate (what should one call it?) the icons in Zurb Foundation?

This gives me a foreground on background color icon.

```
<i class="fi-marker"></i>
```

But I want a background on foreground icon.  I was expecting that it would just be a name change, or add a class?

The [playground page](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3) doesn't seem to have any trouble presenting it on hover so I'm assuming it is a trivial matter:

[image: black on white icons]
[image: white on black icons]

Comment: It's the css `color` property that's changing, just like on a normal font. I guess you'd either have an invert class which you add as and when required, or target the colour of the parent element in your css. I'd normally do the latter, but having a dedicated class is the better way to go I'd say

Comment: indeed it is... what do people do? make a class that just has the color in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they just have just setup a few styles on several of the elements. Here are some styles I extracted from the [playground page](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3).

```
.f-dropdown li:hover, .f-dropdown li:focus {
    background: #eeeeee
}

.f-dropdown.content:hover li {
    background:transparent;
}

.f-dropdown.content:hover {
    background:#000;
}

.f-dropdown.content:hover i {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Hope this helps!